# Android Alarm Not Set

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, alarmmanager, android-doze

I used to set alarms using the following code-segment in other projects as repeating and non-repeating, but it's now driving me crazy about what may the *silly* mistake be that I've made for not the alarm speaking to my current implementation :\ :

```
private fun setAlarm(obj: MyObject, time: Long) {
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MyAlarmIntentService::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(C.KEY_ME, obj)

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext, 43, intent, 
                                          PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    val context = this@MyActivity
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.timeInMillis = time * 1000   // time is in seconds
    Log.d("setAlarm", "setting time -> $time for obj = $obj")
    Log.d("setAlarm", "Set calendar: " + cal.toString())

    val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)  // Overriding doze-mode
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val alarmClockInfo =
                AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(cal.timeInMillis, null)
        alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pendingIntent)
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) // Overriding doze-mode
        // Not-working in Nexus 6 - API 25 (7.1.1), but works in API 23 (6.0.1, tested in multiple devices)
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                    cal.timeInMillis, pendingIntent) 
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) // Works
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
    else // works
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
}
```

The IntentService class is as the following:

```
class MyAlarmIntentService : IntentService("Notification") {

  override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    val obj = intent?.getParcelableExtra<MyObj>(C.KEY_ME) ?: return
    Lg.d(TAG, "My alarm fired for - \n" + obj.toString())
  }

  companion object {
    private val TAG = ContestAlarmIntentService::class.java.simpleName
  }

}
```

The service is declared in manifest as:

```
<service android:name=".services.MyAlarmIntentService" />
```

The following is an example of the mentioned log inside `setAlarm()` method:

```
E/setAlarm: setting time -> 1514993850 for obj = MyObj{...}
E/setAlarm: Set calendar: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1514993850000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Dhaka",mRawOffset=21600000,mEarliestRawOffset=23400000,mUseDst=false,mDstSavings=0,transitions=7],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=1,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_YEAR=3,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=21,MINUTE=37,SECOND=30,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=21600000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

This used to be a straight-forward code to me, but which fundamental may I be missing for **these 3 days'** of test sessions?

Comment: on what android version are you testing this?

Comment: Android 7.1.1 (API 25) - Motorola Nexus 6 and Android 4.4.2 (API 19) - Asus Fonepad 7

Comment: be aware that on Marshmallow and above you've to deal with doze

Comment: how does 'cal.timeInMillis = time * 1000' even compile?

Comment: @A. Kuchinke, it's kotlin.

Comment: @Touhid I know, i tested it in Kotlin and Android Studio complains about types. As the calendar expects a Long but the righthand side is Int

Comment: Oh sorry, in my actual case, `time` is Long type.

Comment: yeah now it makes sense, otherwise you would have gotten a Integer overflow, aside from the type mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I did not go through all your code as I was busy in another task, so here's my code used with Broadcast

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(UtilAlarmConstants.ALARM_ACTION);
pIBroadCast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ALARM_PI_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (alarmManager != null) {

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
          alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(ALARM_TYPE, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);

        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo
                    = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis() + fireAT, null);
            alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pIBroadCast);
        }
        //setExact for 19
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireAT, pIBroadCast);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireAT, pIBroadCast);
        }
    }
```

and Broadcast

```
    if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(UtilAlarmConstants.ALARM_ACTION)) {

            setUpNotification(context, intent);}
```

sorry for not giving answer related to service as they are all same wacky dacky :)

Comment: I can see `alarmManager.setAlarmClock()` is the major difference here. Can you elaborate it's purpose as I got alarm without using it previously? (I'll test your code soon)

Comment: I've found the cause as suggested to handle `Doze mode` by @Benjamin  here[https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#restrictions]: `Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.` Thanks.

Comment: again sorry for being late, set alarm clock is important for an exact time, as a reminder and it does not get affected by Doze but only available +21 device and you will see alarm symbol when you drag down status bar that's it

Comment: the code has worked in android 6.0.1-API 23 (devices: One Plus 2 & Xiaomi Redmi Note 3) & hopefully may work in lower versions, but **NOT in 7.1.1-API 25** (Nexus 6).

I'm now exploring [these sample codes](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager) for any work-around, please inform me if anything comes to your mind.

Comment: setExactAndAllowWhileIdle    ,this does job for nougat, check edited answer

Comment: I already have tested `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`, but it's not working. Please review my updated code-segment.

Comment: in my case, it  works fine, so for your case, either whitelist the app so that no doze effects or use a push msg (fb remote config) which rings instant.let me search and another thing, you are not trying to recurring alarms !